# Basic Excel currency format with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm able to get cells to format as Dates, but I've been unable to get cells to format as currency... Anyone have an example of how to create a style to get this to work?  My code below show the styles I'm creating... the styleDateFormat works like a champ while styleCurrencyFormat has no affect on the cell.

```
private HSSFWorkbook wb;
private HSSFCellStyle styleDateFormat = null;
private HSSFCellStyle styleCurrencyFormat = null;
```

......

```
public CouponicsReportBean(){
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    InitializeFonts();

}

public void InitializeFonts()
{
    styleDateFormat = wb.createCellStyle();
    styleDateFormat.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy"));


    styleCurrencyFormat = wb.createCellStyle();
    styleCurrencyFormat.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("$#,##0.00"));

}
```

Comment: It'll be cool if you can accept your own answer sometime. ;)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After digging through the documentation a bit more, I found the answer:

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataFormat.html

Just need to find an appropriate pre-set format and supply the code.

```
    styleCurrencyFormat.setDataFormat((short)8); //8 = "($#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"
```

Here are more examples:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/poi/setDataFormat.shtml

Comment: The list of built in formats is here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html

Comment: The output looks nice. Pardon me, but if I click on 'Format Cells' in Excel, I just see it falls in the category 'Custom'. Now how can I make it to fall into the category 'Currency'?

Comment: The built-in format table is useful... but who refers to hard-coded numerical values these days? Would it hurt to map POI_FORMAT_CURRENCY=8, etc?

Answer (score 27):

For at least Excel 2010:
Go into Excel. Format a cell they way you want it.

[image]

Then go back into the format dialogue. Select custom.

[image]

Copy paste the text it has on the top row under Type: into

```
createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("<here>");
```

Example:

```
createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* \"-\"??_);_(@_)"); //is the "Accounting" format.
```

**Make sure you set your populate your cells by using a double.**
Using the index may cause problems with different versions of Excel.  Note that the new format you create above ends up in the custom dialogue from step two.

Comment: Great! This is a life saver. I am able to get the Currency correct. That means if I format the cell using this method, when I open the doc in Excel, click on the cell, right click to get 'Format cells', I am able to get the 'Currency' under the format category! Thanks Thanks Thanks

Comment: superb.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Just an update to above reply. short '8' doesn't work for me but the '7' does.

```
cell.setCellValue(416.17);      
cellStyle.setDataFormat((short)7);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

O/P is $416.00

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code to format your cell with currency mode (with thowsand separator like used in Brazil or Germany. Eg. 12.345,67):

```
HSSFCellStyle cell = yourWorkBook.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper ch = yourWorkBook.getCreationHelper();
cell.setDataFormat(ch.createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.00;\\-#,##0.00"));
```