# Formatting Excel cell as Dollar with Apache POI where the machine currency is not dollar

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Java and Apache POI to format an Excel worksheet.

I want to format a cell as dollars.

Using the suggestion in [Basic Excel currency format with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319438/basic-excel-currency-format-with-apache-poi), what I get is that the cell is formatted as shekels (which happens to be the default currency of my machine)

How do I format the cell as dollars, even if the default currency of my machine is not dollars.

The code I am using is as follows

```
CellStyle dollarStyle=wb.createCellStyle();
dollarStyle.setDataFormat(7);
CellUtil.getCell(myRow, 1).setCellStyle(dollarStyle);
```

The number 7 comes from http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html

Comment: What if you try formatting it with an explicit dollar based format, rather than the built in "excel may localise" one?

Comment: Thank you. If you want to repost as an answer than I will accept it, otherwise I posted the code below as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works (this is Gagravarr's suggestion)

```
CellStyle dollarStyle=wb.createCellStyle();
DataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();
dollarStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("$#,#0.00"));
```

Comment: This is making the excel read only in some versions. How do we avoid that?

Comment: I have never encountered this!  Do you mean the entire workbook is read-only, or just that particular cell where you applied the formatting?

Comment: What do you mean by "some versions"? Does the behaviour happen consistently?  Is it possible that you have created too many cellStyles in the workbook? You may want to open a new question, as the code above does work for me and for others.

Comment: I am using excel on mac with version 15.33. It opens in read only mode for me. I haven't checked with other versions on other machines. I assumed if it worked for you and is not working for me, it must be an issue with only some of the versions.