# Apache POI: Accounting format (MUST be presented as "Accounting" in Cell Format dialogue)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, dataformat, cell-formatting

I need to format input text in excel cell to be styled as "Accounting" cell. I'm using this code:

```
HSSFCellStyle styleCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();;
    CreationHelper ch = workbook.getCreationHelper();
    styleCurrency.setDataFormat(ch.createDataFormat().getFormat("_-* # ##0\\ _\u20BD_-;-* # ##0\\ _\u20BD_-;_-* \"-\" _\u20BD_-;_-@_-"));
```

I got the regExp argument from excel cell. ([I found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319438/basic-excel-currency-format-with-apache-poi)). But when i check cell format i get ('custom') instead of ('Accounting'). The text must be written without currency prefix and must be of 'Accounting' format. How to achieve it? I couldn't find any solution in google.

**EDIT:**

My above regExp ("`_-* # ##0\\ _\u20BD_-;-* # ##0\\ _\u20BD_-;_-* \"-\" _\u20BD_-;_-@_-`")

is transfering to: `_-* #\ ##0\ _₽_-;-* #\ ##0\ _₽_-;_-* "-" _₽_-;_-@_-`  in Excel's Cell Format Dialogue...

POI or Excel itself adds slash after first #s.

It must look like this: `_-* # ##0\ _₽_-;-* # ##0\ _₽_-;_-* "-" _₽_-;_-@_-` (whitespace after first #, not slash)

Comment: Enter it how you want in Excel, read that back in POI, see how POI sees the format as encoded in the file, then re-use that?

Comment: @Gagravarr nice workaround! =) But i've already solved it. When i type `# #` in POI excel reads it as `#\#`, to fix it i added comma instead of whitespace. So `#,#` became `# #`. This is weird actually...